# Hash sign (#) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this legacy code that I am working with and there is code like this all over the place:

```
    #If PRE611 = True Then
        'Do Something
    #Else
        'Something Else
    #End If
```

I am pretty sure the PRE611 has something to do with versioning, but I would like to know what specifically the # sign does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are directives, and allows you to do conditional compiling. # sign used for directives.

In this case It will compiled either part of the code based on the evaluation of "PRE611 = True"

You can see this article for some examples :
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/vbdirectives01_2.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It is kind of difficult to search for a # sign.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [pre-processor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099.aspx).

It essentially means if `PRE611` is defined as true (in the pre-processor) to compile whatever follows.